# Lost float in exam class

Tags: tables, floats, positioning, exam

For some reason, I can't seem to put a figure or a table environment inside a solution environment while using the exam class. It produces a float is lost error. Has anyone found a way to bypass this or has an explanation as to why it does not work. I'm thinking it might have to do with how the solution environment is defined, perhaps as a float itself. Here is a sample of code that produces the error.

```
\begin{solution}
Voici le tableau demandé:\\
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\caption{Répartition des collèges publics du Québec selon la langue d'enseignement}
\hline
Langue d'enseignement & Effectifs & Fréquences\\
\hline
Français & $41$ &$ 0.854$\\
\hline
Anglais  & $ 5$ &$ 0.104$\\
\hline
Bilingue & $ 2$ &$ 0.042$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Répartition des collèges publics du Québec selon la langue d'enseignement}
\label{langue2}
\end{table}
\end{solution}
```

Comment: You currently have two `\caption` statements: one of them is redundant, right? It would also be helpful if you converted your code into a Minimum (non)Working Example (MWE).

Comment: yeah, I moved things around trying to solve the problem, one of them has a % before it in my code

Comment: A different method might be to put the float *outside* the `solution` environment (`Voir Tableau~\ref{langue2}`) so that it's allowed to float. I don't think that, if the table is not floating, a caption is necessary.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `solution` environment internally uses a `\vbox` and this has as a consequence that floats are not allowed inside this environment. Instead of using the floating environment `table` you can use a `center` environment
and the `\captionof` command (from the `caption` package) to provide the caption (now the tabular material won't float, of course):

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question Test.
\begin{solution}
Voici le tableau demandé:
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{Répartition des collèges publics du Québec selon la langue d'enseignement}
\label{langue2}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Langue d'enseignement & Effectifs & Fréquences\\
\hline
Français & $41$ &$ 0.854$\\
\hline
Anglais  & $ 5$ &$ 0.104$\\
\hline
Bilingue & $ 2$ &$ 0.042$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{solution}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Not directly related to the issue of the question, but you might be interested in the `booktabs` package to design your tables (vertical rules won't be allowed, but this is an advantage in most cases). Here's the previous code, using `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question Test.
\begin{solution}
Voici le tableau demandé:
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{Répartition des collèges publics du Québec selon la langue d'enseignement}
\label{langue2}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
\toprule
Langue d'enseignement & Effectifs & Fréquences\\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
Français & $41$ &$ 0.854$\\
Anglais  & $ 5$ &$ 0.104$\\
Bilingue & $ 2$ &$ 0.042$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{solution}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A new request has been made in a comment: if `\SolutionEmphasis` has been used to change the solutions formatting, `\captionsetup` can be used so that the formatting for the caption used inside a `solution` environment matches the one of the solutions; a little example in which `\SolutionEmphasis{\color{blue}}` is used:

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionFont{blue}{\color{blue}}
\SolutionEmphasis{\color{blue}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question Test.
\begin{solution}
Voici le tableau demandé:
\begin{center}
\captionsetup{font=blue}
\captionof{table}{Répartition des collèges publics du Québec selon la langue d'enseignement}
\label{langue2}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
\toprule
Langue d'enseignement & Effectifs & Fréquences\\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
Français & $41$ &$ 0.854$\\
Anglais  & $ 5$ &$ 0.104$\\
Bilingue & $ 2$ &$ 0.042$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{solution}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of `font=blue` in the above code, one can use `labelfont=blue` to change only the color for the caption label, or `textcolor=blue` to change only the color for the caption text.

Comment: Thats about what I had resolved to, but I didn't know about captionof so thanks. I was thinking this was related to the solution environment. And yes I agree I need to learn how to design better tables, but for now, this will suffice. Thank you

Comment: Nothing too bad, but I have a solutionemphasis that puts the text color to blue when I print solutions. The label "Table 2"appears black. Do you know of anyway simple way I could change that to blue?

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien of course, it's dinner time here, so in 30minutes I will provide the code. The idea is to use `\captionsetup` to add the blue color to the label.

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien I updated my answer.