# Using table inside solution environment of exam documentclass

Tags: floats, environments, exam

I am trying to use the table environment inside the `solution` environment of the `exam` documentclass. Unfortunately this doesnt work as stated in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74812/158760) question since `table` is also a float.

> The solution environment internally uses a \vbox and this has as a consequence that floats are not allowed inside this environment.  Instead of using the floating environment table you can use a center environment

Since they work outside of the `solution` environment i am looking for a way to modify `\begin{table} ... \end{table}` to act as it is outside the solution and inside replaces itself with `\begin{center}...\end{center}`.

Fortunately as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55864/158760) post shows its easy to find out whether or not you are inside a `solution` environment. I tested this and it works.
However since the documents i have to adapt to the `exam` documentclass are numerous and are also used in other documentclasses I would ideally not create a new environment but adapt the `table` environments similar to what happend [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1566053/5124383) to the `figure` or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2600/158760) to tabular environment. This is my code so far:
**UPDATE:** I dont know why, but with `\center` instead of `\begin{center}` the error is gone and also allows a way to tread the optional argument of `table`

```
\documentclass{exam}

\let\oldtable\table
\let\endoldtable\endtable

\renewenvironment{table}[1][h]
{\ifinner \center    \else  \oldtable[#1] \fi}
{\ifinner \endcenter \else  \endoldtable  \fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions} %error is no \question 
\printanswers

\question{Question featuring a table environment}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{|ll|}
        Question & in  \\
        Question & part \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{solution}
Solution featuring a table environment

    \begin{table}[h]
        \begin{tabular}{|ll|}
            Solution & in  \\
            Solution & part \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{solution}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

<s>But I fear I am not handling the paramter of `table` correct, since this leads to the error: Unknown float option `['. \begin{table}[</s>

This solution works outside "inner" and can handle the optional argument of `table`, however if `\ifinner` is true i get the error

> Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{table}

Does anyone has a suggestion on how to adapt `table` based on the environment?

Thank you very much

Comment: As long as you don't use `\caption`, you can use the `center` environment. If you need a caption, use `\captionof{table}{some caption}`.

Comment: Thanks! This is a solution i can use for future documents, yet i still need a way to handle the existing ones without changeging the `table` parts in them

Comment: In this case, another possibility is to use the ``[H]` placement specifier (defined by the `float` package), which can easily be done with  *Search and Replace* in your editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution and posting it here as answer if someoneelse is facing this issue. The (in hindsight obvious) problem was that `\ifinner` works in the beginning, because it is a floating environment, but as soon as `\table` begins it is not anymore. Therefor the `\endcenter` could no be reached. I have tried a few alternatives and found the easiest way is to define a custom boolean that checks if the `ifinner` of the modified `table` is reached and use this to set a boolean. On the `\endtable`this boolean can then be used to take care of ending it correctly.

```
\let\oldtable\table
\let\endoldtable\endtable
\newif\ifinsidefloatingenv  %set boolean for 
\insidefloatingenvfalse     %not necessary but to be sure its false

\renewenvironment{table}[1][h]
{\ifinner               \center \insidefloatingenvtrue     \else    \oldtable[#1]   \fi}
{\ifinsidefloatingenv   \endcenter \insidefloatingenvfalse \else    \endoldtable    \fi}
```